# iCloud storage showing data for Pages but no documents are saved - what is it?

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, icloud, pages

In my iCloud storage it says that just over 100kb are being used by Pages. I used to use Pages a while back but never saved anything to iCloud drive. On checking iCloud drive there were no documents in there. I'm confused about what data Pages is saving to my iCloud - I know it is a very small amount of memory taken up but just wanted to know if anyone knows what might be saved in there and if it safe to delete it.

There is also around 20kb taken up by iCloud drive - other documents, no idea what this is either.

As seen in the screenshots below there are no documents in either section - just 'data' - whatever that is.[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: did you see the trash of iCloud or recently deleted items there ?

Comment: @ankii yeah I did there's nothing in there, as far as I know I've never saved any Pages document or anything to iCloud drive

Comment: 100k and 20k is a *tiny* amount of data and is likely accounted for by filesystem metadata.

Comment: Have you ever created any documents in Pages at all even if you have not saved them eventually? Have you specifically checked inside the Pages folder directly under the iCloud drive? Pages or other iWork programs such as Numbers like many other macOS programs automatically saves any new file created, even if empty, into iCloud assuming you did not confirm deletions of such documents upon exiting the program.

Comment: @Alper yes I did used to create documents in Pages, however I have never had iCloud drive turned on and always just saved them locally on my mac, there is nothing in the Pages folder or in the whole of my iCloud drive

Comment: I’m sure I can help you clean and understand this with an edit to show a screen shot how you are measuring 20 kB and 100 kB. What steps do you take to get that measurement? Also - while you’re editing it - maybe put in a call to action like “How do I delete files to get these measures to 0? So we know what you want to do - if it’s to understand or to change.

Comment: @bmike I have attached a screenshot, just want to understand what it is really and if I delete it then what am I actually deleting as I don't know what it is in the first place

Comment: Perfect - iOS is seeing data that didn’t sync up. If you’re happy nothing should exist online - tap the delete on iOS to let it purge itself. I wouldn’t worry since it’s parts per million - likely the image for the folder or some generated data that’s left when you make one document and then delete that only document.

Comment: Also - I’ll make an edit later tonight showing how to see the files on macOS in terminal - great info so far

Answer (score 0):

There’s no harm in cleaning up iCloud Documents. I go to the web interface since then I’m 100% sure I see what’s actually in iCloud and not what’s temporarily synced to a device - sometimes a device can lag or get stuck. Cleaning the source is my best advice.

- https://www.icloud.com/iclouddrive/

Before you delete - review recently deleted items and purge them if you want. Then delete all the files you don’t want. Once that’s done on the server side, review that each Mac and iOS device sees the delete or clean out local copies they have that didn’t sync up correctly.

In your images - you can safely clear the data, but if you do the math 101 KB divided by 5.0 GB is 20 parts per million (25 ppm if you include all the other documents as well). It’s not even a rounding error.

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to have an iPhone, it becomes a lot easier.

Currently, I guess that you’re getting the 100kb data via System Preferences -> iCloud -> Manage Storage -> Documents.

This only shows you the used space and a button to delete all there is. That is bad UI.

On iPhone’s equivalent of that setting, you find all documents listed. So since you tagged your post with iPhone too, give it a try.

---

If that also fails, download the relevant data from

https://privacy.apple.com/